# Tkinter customizing ttkthems

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

class MainProgram():
    def __init(self):
            self.root = tk.Tk(className='Papinhio player')
            self.root.title("Papinhio player")
            self.max_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
            self.max_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
            self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.max_width,self.max_height))

            self.style = ThemedStyle(self.root)
            self.style.set_theme_advanced("arc",advanced_name="arc_modified")
            self.style.set_theme("arc_modified")
            self.root.mainloop()
```

I want to change some features of ttkthemes (such as background colour, font size, font colour).

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-custom-ttk-style-same-as-clam-ttk-theme-button-widget-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931533)

Answer (score 0):

`self.style.configure('.', background='green',foreground="blue",font=('Ubuntu', 30))`

It was really simple.

Note: This doesn't apply to root widget.
You can overwrite root style like: `self.root.configure(bg="white")`

Note2: `ttk.Label(self.root,text="Test text").pack()` will work, but

`tk.Label(self.root,text="Test text").pack()` don't.

I don't know why.